# cart items in popup updating only when page is refreshed in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

i have a cart icon on the header.When the page is scrolled this cart icon is floating in a fixed position.when hover over cart icon the cart contents like name price subtotal all are displaying.now when adding a product the cart count is updating correctly.nut cart contents are updating only after refresh.

code of cart in header.php

```
<li>

                <a href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/cart"

                  ><i class="uil uil-shopping-cart-alt"></i>

                  <div>Cart</div></a

                >
                    <span class="counter" id="cart-count"><?php
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    //echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', $cart_count ), $cart_count );
    echo $cart_count;
    ?></span>

              </li>
```

updating cart count code in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_cart_count', 50, 1 );
function refresh_cart_count( $fragments ){
    ob_start();
    ?>
   
    <span class="counter" id="cart-count"><?php
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    //echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', $cart_count ), $cart_count );
    echo $cart_count;
    ?></span>
    <?php
     $fragments['#cart-count'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
```

this is the code displaying when hovering over the cart

```
<div class="miniBasketContent"><div class="miniBasketHeader">Your basket</div><div class="items"><?php


 global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    $total =  $woocommerce->cart->total;
    
        foreach($items as $item => $values) { $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id() );$getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );$price = get_post_meta($values['product_id'] , '_price', true);?><div class="item"><div class="image"><?php echo $getProductDetail->get_image();?></div><div class="info"><a href="/shop/default.asp?productid=106-286-204"><?php echo $_product->get_title();?></a></div><div class="price"><?php echo $price;?> AED</div></div><?php } ?></div><div class="miniBasketFooter"><div class="info"><div class="total"><span><?php echo $total; ?>AED</span>Total</div><a href="/shop/showbasket.html">Show basket</a><a href="/shop/checkout.html">Go to checkout</a></div></div></div>
```

what to do to update cart contents inside popup without reloading page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution

`demo_cart_link()` Use this function where you want to display cart count HTML.

function.php

```
if ( defined( 'WC_VERSION' ) && version_compare( WC_VERSION, '2.3', '>=' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'demo_cart_link_fragment', 10 , 1 );
} else {
    add_filter( 'add_to_cart_fragments', 'demo_cart_link_fragment', 10 , 1 );
}
if ( ! function_exists( 'demo_cart_link_fragment' ) ) {
    function demo_cart_link_fragment( $fragments ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        ob_start();
        demo_cart_link();
        $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();
        return $fragments;
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'demo_cart_link' ) ) {
    function demo_cart_link() {
?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'paperfig' ); ?>" type="button" data-toggle="modal">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
        <span class="cart-numbers"><?php echo wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( ' %d', ' %d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'paperfig' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) );?></span>
    </a>
<?php
    }
}
```